# command prompt unable to access jarfile

Tags: command-line, executable-jar

This one is for a Minecraft server. When I try to access the jarfile this is what I am putting in

`java -jar "C:\Users\Erik\Desktop\ForgeServer\forge-1.11.2-12.20.0.2282-universal.jar"`

I have even tried `javaw` rather then `java`.

The whole reason I need to access it is to allocate more RAM for the server. Which would be:

`java -Xmx7g -Xms5g -jar "C:\Users\Erik\Desktop\ForgeServer\forge-1.11.2-12.20.0.2282-universal.jar"`

But no matter how I do it, it still says unable to access jarfile. The jarfile is executable.

Comment: make sure the file is accessible for the java(permission,  ...). Plus please share the message you face too. Also never seen 5G min heap size! I also think `/` works for windows too in java

Comment: unable to access jarfile "C:\Users\Erik\Desktop\ForgeServer\forge-1.11.2-12.20.0.2282-universal.jar"  

is the full error message. 

How do I access the specific permissions? I can't find it in preferences

Comment: what about `java -jar "C:/Users/Erik/Desktop/ForgeServer/forge-1.11.2-12.20.0.2282‌​-universal.jar"` ?

Comment: error message is the same

Comment: try `runas.exe /savecred /user:administrator java -jar "C:\Users\Erik\Desktop\ForgeServer\forge-1.11.2-12.20.0.2282-universal.jar"` .

Comment: That didn't seem to work.

Notes are:

     Enter user's password only when prompted
     /profile is not compatible with /netonly
     /savecred is not compatable with /smartcard

Comment: This is really weird dear. You may please make sure about the path again. even change the current location to the folder the jar located and invoke the jar file with relative path. Plus make sure it's accessible(can read). I really cannot say anything certain about it dear.

Comment: I can't seem to find the (can read) option. I found Read-only but that didn't help. Sorry for the late responses.

Comment: Also make sure about the permission https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727008.aspx